# req.session returns undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, ajax, session

I've tried many ways but I still get undefined when I log my sessions

[Get "undefined" for req.session in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943457/get-undefined-for-req-session-in-nodejs)
[Session in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778068/session-in-nodejs)

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'mYsEcReTkEy',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false }
}));

app.use('/users/data' , getUserData);
app.get('/order/new' , addOrderPage)

  addOrderPage: (req, res) => {
    console.log('ll', req.session.userData);},

getUserData: (req, res) => {
  let userData = req.query.userData;
    req.session.userData = userData;
    console.log('ll55', req.session.userData);
}
```

in my log i got the first one ehere I set my session but the next I got undefined

Comment: how are you making the request?

Comment: can't understamd what you mean?